# Как использовать TreeView в C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms, treeview

У меня есть несколько текстовых файлов в которых публикуется информация о вакансиях. Моя задача обработать текст. В результате получится такая иерархия данных:

- Список дат публикации статей.
- Дата статьи.
- Список компаний на эту дату.
- Компания и её описание.
- Список вакансий этой компании.
- Вакансия и её описание.

Создал три папки `DAL`, `BLL`, `UI`. В `DAL` разместил класс обрабатывающий текстовые файлы и превращающий их в единый список строк. И класс ключевых слов. В `BLL` разместил классы: `Company`, `Vacancy`, `DateOfArticle` и собственно `Sborka` в которой уже вся логика. В результате у меня данные организованы в иерархии которую я описал. Ну и в `UI` расположена `WebForm` Теперь задача вывести это в `TreeView`. Не могу найти более или менее вменяемого описания как `TreeView` работает. Может быть кто-нибудь мне может на пальцах объяснить, как мне, сформированные у меня данные, разместить в этой штуке?

```
namespace JS_Project.BLL
{
    public class Sborka
    {
        //создаём коллекцию дат
        private List<DateOfArticle> list_of_dates = new List<DateOfArticle>();

        //создаём экземпляр класса Data, в результате в конструкторе Дата создаётся коллекция всех строк всех статей
        DAL.Data data = new DAL.Data();

        //объявляем коллекцию для всех строк статей
        private List<string> all_lines_articles;

        //забираем коллекцию всех строк статей из класса Data
        public void Get_All_Line_Articles()
        {
            this.all_lines_articles = data.Get_All_Lines_Articles();
        }

        //создаём экземпляр класса ключевых слов
        DAL.KeyWords Keywords = new DAL.KeyWords();

        //создаём экземпляр списка для ключевых слов
        List<string> list_key_words = new List<string>(); 

        //объявляем библиотеку ключевое слово - запускаемый метод
        Dictionary<string, Action<string>> keywordHandlers;

        //объявляем переменную стринг для одной строки статьи
        string line;
        //создаём единый счётчик для всех циклов
        private int i;
        //создаём индексы активных объектов
        private int index_list_of_dates;
        private int index_of_company;
        private int index_of_vacancy;
        //находим в тексте дату опубликования статьи и создаём объект DateOfArticle
        public void Search_date_of_article()
        {
            for (this.i += 0; i < this.all_lines_articles.Count; i++)
            {
                 line = all_lines_articles[i];
                //находим дату в тексте
                if (line.Contains(DAL.KeyWords.DATE))
                {
                    this.Set_date_of_article();
                }
            }
        }
        //метод создания новой даты
        public void Set_date_of_article()
        {
            line = all_lines_articles[this.i];
            string date_of_article = line.Substring(7, line.Length - 7);
            //создаём объект ДатаСтатьи в котором автоматически объект - создаётся пустой список компаний
            this.list_of_dates.Add(new DateOfArticle(date_of_article));
            //передаём индекс созданной даты для дальнейшего использования
            this.index_list_of_dates = this.list_of_dates.Count - 1;
            //запускаем метод поиска ключевого слова списка компаний
            Search_Key_List_Companies();
        }
        //находим в тексте ключевое слово листа компаний
        public void Search_Key_List_Companies()
        {
            for (this.i += 1; i < this.all_lines_articles.Count; i++)
            {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];
                //если в ней список компаний ...
                if (line.Contains(DAL.KeyWords.LIST_COMPANIES))
                {
                    //запускаем метод формирования списка компаний
                    this.Set_List_Companies();
                }
            }
        }

        //метод формирования списка компаний
        public void Set_List_Companies()
        {
            for (this.i += 2; i < all_lines_articles.Count; i++)
            {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];

                if (line != DAL.KeyWords.EMPTY)
                {
                    //и в последнюю созданную дату, в её список компаний добавляю новую компанию с именем из имеющейся строки
                    this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies.Add(new Company(line));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Search_key_list_vacancy();
                }
            }
        }


        //находим в тексте ключевое слово листа вакансий
        public void Search_key_list_vacancy()
        {
            for (this.i += 1; i < this.all_lines_articles.Count; i++)
            {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];
                // если в ней список вакансий - запускаем метод обработки списка вакансий
                if (line.Contains(DAL.KeyWords.LIST_VACANCIES))
                {
                    this.Set_List_Vacancies();
                }
            }
        }

        //метод формирования  общего списка вакансий
        public void Set_List_Vacancies()
        {
            for (this.i += 2; i < all_lines_articles.Count; i++)
            {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];
                if (line != DAL.KeyWords.EMPTY)
                {
                    string name_vacancy = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 2);
                    this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_all_vacancies.Add(new Vacancy(name_vacancy));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Search_key_Company();
                }
            }

        }

        //метод поиска маркера компании
        public void Search_key_Company()

        {
            for (this.i += 1; i < all_lines_articles.Count; i++)
            {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];
                if (line.Contains(DAL.KeyWords.COMPANY))
                {
                    //вычленяем название из строки
                    string name_current_company = line.Substring(3, line.Length - 3);
                    //ищем название в списке компаний
                    for (this.index_of_company = 0; this.index_of_company < this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies.Count; this.index_of_company++)
                    {
                        string name_company = this.list_of_dates[list_of_dates.Count - 1].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].Get_Company_Name();
                        if (name_current_company == name_company)
                        {
                            Set_Description_Company();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (line.Contains(DAL.KeyWords.END_OF_REPORT))
                    {
                        this.Search_date_of_article();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //метод формирования описания компании
        public void Set_Description_Company()
        {
            for (this.i += 2; i < all_lines_articles.Count; i++)
            {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];
                if (line.Length > 5)
                {
                    //заполняем поле описание компании
                    this.list_of_dates[list_of_dates.Count - 1].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].Company_dscrp += line;
                }
                else
                {
                    Search_key_words();
                }
            }
        }
         //метод поиска ключевых слов компании и вакансии
        public void Search_key_words()
        {
            this.Create_dict_keywordHandlers();

            for (this.i += 1; i < this.all_lines_articles.Count; i ++ )
            {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];
                foreach (var kwh in keywordHandlers)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(kwh.Key))
                    {
                        kwh.Value(line);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void Set_address_company()
        {
            line = this.all_lines_articles[i];
            string address = line.Substring(9, line.Length - 9);
            this.list_of_dates[this.list_of_dates.Count - 1].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].Company_address = address;
        } 

        public void Set_num_employees()
        {
            {
                line = this.all_lines_articles[i];
                string num_employees = line.Substring(28, line.Length - 28);
                this.list_of_dates[this.list_of_dates.Count - 1].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].Company_num_employees = num_employees;
            }
        }

        public void Set_the_year_of_establishment()
        {
            line = this.all_lines_articles[i];
            string year_of_establishment = line.Substring(21, line.Length - 21);
            this.list_of_dates[this.list_of_dates.Count - 1].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].Company_estblsh = year_of_establishment;

        }
        public void Set_phone_number_of_company()
        {
            line = this.all_lines_articles[i];
            string phone_number = line.Substring(7, line.Length - 7);
            this.list_of_dates[this.list_of_dates.Count - 1].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].Company_phone = phone_number;
        }
        public void Set_fax_number_of_company()
        {
            line = this.all_lines_articles[i];
            string fax_number = line.Substring(5, line.Length - 5);
            this.list_of_dates[this.list_of_dates.Count - 1].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].Company_fax = fax_number;
        }

        public void Set_contact_of_company()
        {
            line = this.all_lines_articles[i];
            string contact_of_company = line.Substring(9, line.Length - 9);
            this.list_of_dates[this.list_of_dates.Count - 1].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].Company_contact = contact_of_company;
        }
        public void Set_email_of_company()
        {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];
                string email_of_company = line.Substring(6, line.Length - 6);
                this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies[index_of_company].Company_email = email_of_company;
        }
        public void Set_website_of_company ()
        {
            line = all_lines_articles[i];
            string website_of_company = line.Substring(10, line.Length - 10);
            this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies[index_of_company].Company_webSt = website_of_company;

        }
        public void Search_key_set_vacancy()
        {
            for (this.i += 1; i < all_lines_articles.Count; i++)
            {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];
                if (line.Contains(DAL.KeyWords.KEY_VACANCY))
                {
                    //забираем из line название вакансии
                    string name_vacancy = line.Substring(4, line.Length - 4);
                    //создаём новую вакансию и передаём ей в параметре её название
                    this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].List_vacancies.Add(new Vacancy(name_vacancy));
                    //передаём индекс созданной вакансии для дальнейшего использования
                    this.index_of_vacancy = this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies[index_of_company].List_vacancies.Count - 1;
                    //устанавливаем имя компании
                    string name_of_company = this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies[index_of_company].Get_Company_Name();
                    this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies[index_of_company].List_vacancies[index_of_vacancy].Company_name = name_of_company;
                    //устанавливаем дату обновления для вакансии
                    for (this.i += 2; i < all_lines_articles.Count; i++)
                    {
                        line = all_lines_articles[i];
                        if (line.Contains(DAL.KeyWords.UPDATE))
                        {
                            string date_update = line.Substring(9, line.Length - 9);
                            this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies[this.index_of_company].List_vacancies[index_of_vacancy].Update = date_update;
                        }
                            Search_key_set_description_vacancy();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void Search_key_set_description_vacancy()
        {
            for (this.i += 0; this.i < all_lines_articles.Count; this.i++)
            {
                line = all_lines_articles[i];
                if (line.Contains(DAL.KeyWords.KEY_DESCRIPTION_VACANCY))
                {
                    //заполняем поле вакансии
                    string start_description_vacancy = line.Substring(13, line.Length - 13);
                    this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies[index_of_company].List_vacancies[index_of_vacancy].Vacancy_description = start_description_vacancy;
                    for (this.i += 1; this.i < this.all_lines_articles.Count; this.i++)
                    {
                        line = all_lines_articles[this.i];

                        if  (line == DAL.KeyWords.SEPATOR_13)
                        {
                            this.Search_key_set_vacancy();
                        }
                        else if (line.Contains(DAL.KeyWords.GENERAL_SEPARATOR))
                        {
                            this.Search_key_Company();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.list_of_dates[index_list_of_dates].List_of_companies[index_of_company].List_vacancies[index_of_vacancy].Vacancy_description += line;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //блок пар: ключевое слово - запускаемый метод
        public void Create_dict_keywordHandlers()
        {
            this.keywordHandlers = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>();

            keywordHandlers.Add("Address: ",                    (s) => this.Set_address_company());
            keywordHandlers.Add("No. of Employees in Israel:",  (s) => this.Set_num_employees());
            keywordHandlers.Add("Company Established:",         (s) => this.Set_the_year_of_establishment());
            keywordHandlers.Add("Phone:",                       (s) => this.Set_phone_number_of_company());
            keywordHandlers.Add("Fax:",                         (s) => this.Set_fax_number_of_company());
            keywordHandlers.Add("Email:",                       (s) => this.Set_email_of_company());
            keywordHandlers.Add("Contact: ",                    (s) => this.Set_contact_of_company());
            keywordHandlers.Add("Web Site:",                    (s) => this.Set_website_of_company());
            keywordHandlers.Add("-------------",                (s) => this.Search_key_set_vacancy());
            keywordHandlers.Add("Dates: ",                      (s) => this.Set_date_of_article());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит в вопросе указать язык программирования.

Comment: Прошу прощения, язык C#

Comment: @DavidWillart: И ещё UI framework. Под C# обычно пользуются WinForms и WPF.

Comment: Ок. Я создал WebForm. Создал три папки DAL, BLL, UI. В DAL разместил класс обрабатывающий текстовые файлы и превращающий их в единый список строк. И класс ключевых слов.
В BLL разместил классы: Company, Vacancy, DateOfArticle и собственно Sborka в которой уже вся логика. В результате у меня данные организованы в иерархии которую я описал. Ну и в UI расположена WebForm

Comment: @DavidWillart: Ах, это **WebForms**! Тогда это не ко мне. Добавлю-ка я метку. И вы бы поместили дополнительную информацию в вопрос (его можно редактировать).

Comment: @DavidWillart WebForm - т.е. вы создает веб-сайт. как использовать treeview - [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms529261(v=vs.85).aspx)